# get value from checkbox and use in other activity

Tags: android, checkbox, global-variables

I need that when checkbox in the "true" some variable changed  its a value and this variable was available elsewhere(in other Activity).
When variable acquires some value, TextView in another Activity changed text

Answer (score 0):

If( .isSelected( ) == true){ .setText(  "" + .getText( ) ) ;
 }

Here  is you checkbox and  is where you want to display the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get value from checkbox :
First define a CheckBox and a Button in .xml file ,Then in onCreate() of your Corresponding java (Lets say MainActivity.java) file do following code .

Step 1 :

```
CheckBox hkIos = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkIos);
Button btn = (Button ) findViewById(R.id.btnId);
```

Step 2 :

```
    btn .setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
     //Now send checkStatus to another activity ,lets say MyActivity.java
     boolean checkStatus = hkIos.isChecked();
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("checkBoxStatus",checkStatus);
                startActivity(intent );
                }
            });
```

Step 3 :
Now in onCreate() method of MyActivity.java use following code to get **checkStatus**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
boolean checkBoxStatus = intent.getBooleanExtra("checkBoxStatus");
```

Now you can use checkBoxStatus here .

Comment: Error:(33, 15) error: non-static method putExtra(String,boolean) cannot be referenced from a static context                                                                         in the line intent.putExtra("checkBoxStatus",checkStatus);

Comment: As I m getting you are trying to call intent.puExtra in a static method ,so put this code in a non-static method of your activity .

Comment: @SauliakKolia I have edited the Answer according to your requirement , Follow same steps as I have mentioned .

Comment: Don't forget to mention MyActivity.java file in AndroidManifest.xml .